# php conditional syntax; both branches appearing

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, mamp

A php 'if statement' example from a tutorial [by Kevin Yank](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/19.html) doesn't seem to work. Specifically, both branches of the conditional appear when the page loads.
I have also tried changing to the non-shorthand 'if' syntax, to no avail.
Is the problem something other than syntax?

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample Page </title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if(isset($name)) : ?>
    <p> Your name: <?php echo ($name); ?> </p>
    <p> This paragraph contains a <a href="goodone.php"> link</a> that passes the name variable on to the next document. </p> 

<?php else : ?>  
    <!-- No name has been provided, so prompt the user for one -->

    <form action="<php echo($PHP_SELF); ?>" method="get">
    Please enter your user name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
    </form>

<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code? I just copied everything you posted and ran it, and it works properly showing only the portion after `else` because `$name` is not set.

Comment: `action="<php echo($PHP_SELF); ?>"` effectively is same as `action=""`.

Comment: This script left out one important element `$name=$_GET['name'];` Add that above `if(isset($name))` so that it now reads as `<?php  $name=$_GET['name']; if (isset($name)): ?>` and it will work. (TESTED)

Comment: See my answer below (tested and now working)

Comment: Nick Coons - that is indeed the entirety of the code. I'm at a loss to  see a syntax error...
hjpotter - I think the idea is for that statement to appear in the 'else' branch of the conditional, prompting the user to enter a name where one is not present

Since the code has worked correctly for others, should I start looking into my MAMP settings?

Comment: @user2651379 I'm Googling this as we speak, in regards to the new developments (`MAMP`). From what I gathered so far, it might be the way the action is set. Try something to the affect of `action="Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_file.php"` although I'm not entirely certain this will work.

Comment: @user2651379 Here's something which may be of help http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/144710-serverphp-self-on-mamp-is-not-working/ (I know nothing about MAMP or other local web server stuff).

Comment: @user2651379 Try setting your `register globals` to "ON" in your `php.ini` file, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

[**This script**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/19.html) **left out a very important element** >>> `$name=$_GET['name'];` <<<

The `name` must first be declared as a variable.

It has been added inside this line: `<?php if(isset($name)) : ?>`

See my code below: (tested and working)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Sample Page </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<?php $name=$_GET['name']; if (isset($name)): ?>

  <P>Your name: <?php echo($name); ?></P>

  <P>This paragraph contains a
<A HREF="newpage.php?name=<?php echo(urlencode
($name)); ?>">link</A> that passes the
name variable on to the next document.</P>

<?php else: ?>

  <!-- No name has been provided, so we
       prompt the user for one.         -->

  <FORM ACTION="<?php echo($PHP_SELF); ?>" METHOD="GET">
  Please enter your name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="name">
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="GO">
  </FORM>

<?php endif; ?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Plus as an added bonus** (tested and working), you can use the PHP code below, inside your `goodone.php` file to `echo` the name after you clicked on the link after you submitted the form. You can do whatever you wish from hereonin, for database use, etc.

```
<?php 

echo($_GET['name']);

// do something else

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Fred - adding the extra statement has made no difference in my case; the page still loads with the output for both branches, although I understand in principle what your amendment would achieve.
I must be unwittingly causing the error in some other way.

Comment: @user2651379 You're welcome. Yet I can't understand why it wouldn't work for you. I fully tested my code and it worked like a charm. What exactly are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @user2651379 I noticed your message just now about `MAMP`, so you're running this locally then. I just added the relevant TAG.